# I am trying to make a text box only be able to have 4 Digits within it

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a text box only allow a maximum of 4 digits within it and make an alert message box if there is any less than 4. I have managed to do this by using this code.

```
  <tr>
     <td  id="ExamNumber">ExamNumber </td>
     <td> <input type="text" name="ExamNumber" maxlength="4"
          <font size="1">(Maximum characters: 4)</font> </td>
</tr>

if (document.ExamEntry.ExamNumber.value.length!=4) {
   msg+="You must enter at least Four Numbers in the Examination Number \n";
   document.ExamEntry.ExamNumber.focus();
   document.getElementById('ExamNumber').style.color="red";
   result = false;
}
```

However the textbox has shrunk in size and looks odd compared to the other text boxes in the code and it is not digits only there are still letters and symbols allowed within the text field. Please help and thank you in advance. The full list of code is below if it helps:

```
<head>
<title>Exam Entry Form</title>

<script language = "javascript" type = "text/javascript">

function validateForm() {
var result = true;
var msg="";


if (document.ExamEntry.name.value=="") {
   msg+="You must enter your name \n";
   document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
   document.getElementById('name').style.color="red";
   result = false;
}


if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value=="") {
   msg+="You must enter the subject \n";
   document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
   document.getElementById('subject').style.color="red";
   result = false;
}

    if (document.ExamEntry.ExamNumber.value=="") {
   msg+="You must enter the Exam Number \n";
   document.ExamEntry.ExamNumber.focus();
   document.getElementById('ExamNumber').style.color="red";
   result = false;
}

if (document.ExamEntry.ExamNumber.value.length!=4) {
   msg+="You must enter at least Four Numbers in the Examination Number \n";
   document.ExamEntry.ExamNumber.focus();
   document.getElementById('ExamNumber').style.color="red";
   result = false;
}   



if(msg==""){
return result;
}

{
alert(msg)
return result;
}

}

</script>

</head>

<body>
<h1>Exam Entry Form</h1>
<form name="ExamEntry" method="post" action="success.html">
<table width="50%" border ="0">
<tr>
   <td id="name">Name</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td id="subject">Subject</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="subject" /></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
     <td  id="ExamNumber">ExamNumber </td>
     <td> <input type="text" name="ExamNumber" maxlength="4"
          <font size="1">(Maximum characters: 4)</font> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateForm();"             \></td>
<td><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" /></td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: maxlength doesn't allow you to type more than 4 chars

Answer (score 0):

Use below code on keypress to allow only numeric keys. And for width of textbox, specify width in style.

```
function NumericCharKeyPress()
{
if ((event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57))
{
    return true;
}
return false;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to adjust width:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="4" size="10" />
```

or

```
<input type="text" maxlength="4" style="width:100px;" />
```